# Conditionally remove row from table in Power Query or PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, powerquery

I have a list of employees and for some employees I have two rows when they changed from contract to permanent. **I like to remove the row where the employee was a contracter.**

| employeeID | EmployeeType | Other Employee Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 216 | contract | drop this row |
| 641 | fulltime |  |
| 216 | fulltime |  |
| 853 | contract |  |

I want to be the output

| employeeID | EmployeeType | Other Employee Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 641 | fulltime |  |
| 216 | fulltime |  |
| 853 | contract |  |

Any suggestions how I can do this in Power Query (for testing) and / or PostgreSQL (final implementation) ?

**EDIT: 2022/01/17**

@ron-rosenfeld kindly provided the solution for Power Query below. I will try to summarize it here. Any inaccuracy is due to my lack of understanding.

- specify the columns to group by ([Microsoft Table.Group() Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-group))
- specify the aggregation with a new column name and return the sub-table in the aggregation

  - we create filtered table which removes the "contract" from the sub-table
  - if the the number of records in the sub-table is more than 1 we return the filtered sub-table else the sub-table itself
- expand the returned record

```
let
    Source = _my source_
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"employeeID"}, {
        {"TempTable", (t)=> 
            let ft = Table.SelectRows(t, each [EmployeeType] <> "contract")
            in if Table.RowCount(t) > 1 then ft{0} else t{0}
        }
    }),
    #"Expanded Employee Type" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "TempTable", {"EmployeeType", "Other Employee Data"}, {"EmployeeType", "Other Employee Data"})
in 
    #"Expanded Employee Type"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And in Power Query:

- Group by ID
- Then create a custom aggregation to

  - Filter each subtable to return only "fulltime"
  - If there are no rows after filtering, return the first "Type", otherwise return full time

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table15"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"employeeID", Int64.Type}, {"EmployeeType", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"employeeID"}, {
        {"Employee Type", (t) => 
            let 
                ft = Table.SelectRows(t, each [EmployeeType] = "fulltime")
            in 
                if Table.RowCount(ft) > 0 then "fulltime" else t[EmployeeType]{0}}
    })
in 
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

***Edit:** To return the entire filtered row instead of just the Type, merely change the aggregation to return the relevant record, then expand that column. eg*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"employeeID", Int64.Type}, {"EmployeeType", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"employeeID"}, {
        {"Employee Type", (t) => 
            let 
                ft = Table.SelectRows(t, each [EmployeeType] = "fulltime")
            in 
                if Table.RowCount(ft) > 0 then ft{0} else t{0}}
    }),
    #"Expanded Employee Type" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Employee Type", {"EmployeeType", "Other Employee Data"}, {"EmployeeType", "Other Employee Data"})
in 
    #"Expanded Employee Type"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I understand what it does, but I am not familiar with the syntax. If I break it down as (t) => let ft = "table with rows filtered on 'fulltime'" in "return value based on row count of table ft. What do the operators "=>" and "in" do here?

Comment: @Orandasoft `=>` passes the argument `(t)` to the aggregation function.  And every `let` requires an `in`.  `(t)` is the subtable being  passed by the `Table.Group` function.  And I could have nested the `SelectRows` with the `RowCount` (and avoided the `let..in`), but at the time I was designing, I thought I might have to refer to the filtered table more than once.   `(t)=> if Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(t, each [EmployeeType] = "fulltime")) > 0 then "fulltime" else t[EmployeeType]{0}` works also in this particular data set.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The result would be two columns, but what if I would like to have the full row?

Comment: @Orandasoft You just change the aggregation to return a Record instead; then expand that column.  I'll add edited code to my answer.

Comment: I am learning a lot from this. However, if I understand correctly, it filters the sub-table for fulltime employee and if there are any it returns the filtered sub-table else it returns the sub-table itself. What I really like to to do is if the sub-table has more than one entry, filter out the contracters.

Comment: I think this should work: (t)=> let ft = Table.SelectRows(t, each [EmployeeType] <> "contract") in if Table.RowCount(t) > 1 then ft{0} else t{0}

Comment: @Orandasoft Absolutely that will work to remove those rows in your example.  The only consideration, and the reason I did it the way I proposed, was in case you had additional employee types that also needed to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE  employeeid IN (SELECT employeeid
                      FROM   tab
                      GROUP  BY employeeid
                      HAVING Count(*) > 1)
       AND employeetype = 'contract';
```

Full Execution:

```
postgres=# create table tab(employeeid int,employeetype varchar(20));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into tab values(216,'contract'),(641,'fulltime'),(216,'fulltime'),(851,'contract');
INSERT 0 4
postgres=# select * from tab;
 employeeid | employeetype
------------+--------------
        216 | contract
        641 | fulltime
        216 | fulltime
        851 | contract
(4 rows)

postgres=# delete from Tab where employeeid in (select employeeid from tab group by employeeid having count(*)>1) and employeetype='contract';
DELETE 1
postgres=# select * from tab;
 employeeid | employeetype
------------+--------------
        641 | fulltime
        216 | fulltime
        851 | contract
(3 rows)
```

**Edit 16th Jan 2022** List all rows excluding employees who have been been previously contractors. Rows for either directly fulltime or are directly contractors.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tab
WHERE  employeeid NOT IN (SELECT employeeid
                          FROM   tab
                          GROUP  BY employeeid
                          HAVING Count(*) > 1);
```

Full Execution:

```
postgres=# truncate table tab;
TRUNCATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into tab values(216,'contract'),(641,'fulltime'),(216,'fulltime'),(851,'contract');
INSERT 0 4
postgres=# select * from tab;
 employeeid | employeetype
------------+--------------
        216 | contract
        641 | fulltime
        216 | fulltime
        851 | contract

postgres=# SELECT *
postgres-# FROM   tab
postgres-# WHERE  employeeid NOT IN (SELECT employeeid
postgres(#                           FROM   tab
postgres(#                           GROUP  BY employeeid
postgres(#                           HAVING Count(*) > 1);
 employeeid | employeetype
------------+--------------
        641 | fulltime
        851 | contract
(2 rows)
```

**Edit 17th Jan 2022** List of rows after excluding the contract entries for an employee with both Fulltime entry as well as contract entry by using ANTI-JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tab outer_tab
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   tab inner_tab
                   WHERE  inner_tab.employeeid = outer_tab.employeeid
                          AND inner_tab.employeetype = 'fulltime'
                          AND outer_tab.employeetype = 'contract');
```

Execution:

```
postgres=# SELECT *
postgres-# FROM   tab outer_tab
postgres-# WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
postgres(#                    FROM   tab inner_tab
postgres(#                    WHERE  inner_tab.employeeid = outer_tab.employeeid
postgres(#                           AND inner_tab.employeetype = 'fulltime'
postgres(#                           AND outer_tab.employeetype = 'contract');
 employeeid | employeetype
------------+--------------
        641 | fulltime
        216 | fulltime
        851 | contract
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't mention this above to keep it simple, but what if there are a number of table entries where the employee ID is null? In that case, the count would be > 1. However, I do not want to delete those rows where the employeeID is null.

Comment: @Orandasoft In case employeid is NULL , how do you identify an employee? Maybe you can update the example entries in the original post and then show the desired output to be clear.

Comment: I tried to simplify the problem. Actually, the employeeid is part of the problem, because the employee gets assigned a new employeeid when the employee joins as a fulltime employee. There is another field which is unique and which is remains the same even if the employee because a fulltime employee. However, there are a few edge cases where HR has not filled out this field and the value is null. It is this field which I want to use to group the employees by.

Comment: @Orandasoft I believe I am getting your problem and it seems , there are rows with the NULL in the column with unique values. In that case, you need at least one other column to identify the row, something like 'employee name' . Otherwise you have bunch of orphan rows which will be impossible to identify. You will need to reverse engineer a lot, digging into other places in the app or some entries in related tables which might hold some clue.

Comment: Thanks. How would the SQL look like if I would like to do a SELECT * but not include the rows where the employee was previously a contractor (but not delete the row from the table)?

Comment: Provided the SQL in the new edit.

Comment: Thanks Rajorshi. This will exclude all employees which have been a contractor. I would like to exclude only the contractor rows for those employees, but keep any other row.

Comment: The following query seems to work. Is it correct and at the same time most efficient. SELECT * FROM   tab WHERE  (employeeid NOT IN (SELECT employeeid FROM   tab GROUP  BY employeeid HAVING Count(*) > 1)) OR (employeeid IN (SELECT employeeid FROM   tab GROUP  BY employeeid HAVING Count(*) > 1) AND employeetype <> 'contract');

Comment: You need to use ANTI-JOIN (not exists) rather than scanning the table multiple times (3 times in the SQL you provided). New SQL in new Edit.ref: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/join-strategies-and-performance-in-postgresql/

Comment: Assuming there would more bore employment types, would it be more flexible to say SELECT * FROM   tab outer_tab WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   tab inner_tab  WHERE  inner_tab.employeeid = outer_tab.employeeid AND inner_tab.employeetype <> 'contract' AND outer_tab.employeetype = 'contract');

Comment: No, it won't , in that case, we will have to reduce to two types of employee to "FULLTIME" and "TEMPORARY" but before that the situation gives rise to a question. Say, an employee status was "CONTRACT" and now its "PARTTIME" and have never been "FULLTIME", so you have two records one "CONTRACT" and other "PARTTIME",  If it were only "CONTRACT" you would retain "CONTRACT" . But what if you have two types "CONTRACT" and "PARTTIME"?Based on the answer , we will craft the SQL.